# Watching for any change vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

My question is how to watch for any state changes inside the store. I've seen examples where we are looking at a specific property in the state, but in my case, I need to know if anything changed, no matter if I have 1 or more properties.

GOAL:
The goal is to know if anything changed so we can prompt the user to click Save Changes. We are using store because these setting are located in different modals/components. And we have 4 stores for different stuff, and we need a global Save button that will save everything from all stores. So I need to watch any changes two modules state

example:

inside a module
globalSettingsModule.js

```
export const globalSettingsModule = {
state:{
   name:'',
   surname:'',
   password:'',
   defaultTime:'',
},
mutations: {},
actions: {},

}
```

Now I want to know if any of these has changed (name, surname, password, defaultTime) or any other properties that might be added by other developers in the future.

The goal here is to implement a way to detect changes in the settings we have so that I can inform the user that they have unsaved changes if they try to navigate away without saving. It's tedious to compare one by one in all the fields since there might be more in the future. So is there a way to watch the actual `store` itself.

I think I have a way of doing this, by subscribing to mutations, and we can assume something was changed. But we have 2 stores/modules for now, more might be added.

I come from React, there I would check the state ref since a new object is assigned always, but here in vue we mutate the state so I don't know how to do this correctly.